# Residual Risk and Variance

Tags: capm, variance, asset-allocation, minimum-variance

[image]

I've solved part a, but am struggling with b and c. $x_m$ is the market portfolio vector, and I think $T$ should be a diagonal matrix. Any hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, T is a diagonal matrix with $Var(\epsilon_i)$ in (i,i) and zeroes outside the main diagonal.